# How to calculate the volume of $\cos(x)$ around the x-axis and the y-axis separately?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I have difficulties finding the right formula how to calculate the volume rotating $\cos(x)$ around the x-axis and y-axis separately can you please give me a hint how to do it?

the interval is $x=[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1) Around the x-axis, you get $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \pi (\cos x)^2dx=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \pi (\cos x)^2dx$,

$\;\;\;$using the Disc method 
(and symmetry).

2) Around the y-axis, you get $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2\pi x\cos x\; dx$, using the Shell method.

$\;\;\;$(Notice that the right half of the region generates the whole solid in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

HINT : Draw the figure, and you'll see the reason of the following formula :

1) $x$-axis case : 
$$\pi\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}y^2dx$$
where $y=\cos x.$

2) $y$-axis case :
$$\pi\int_{0}^{1}x^2dy.$$
Do you know how to calculate this?

Comment: I know how to calculate it, but please tell me why $x^2$ in the 2) case because I have found a formula $2\pi\int_{a}^{b}xydx$

Comment: Do you really understand the 1) case? The idea of the case 2) is the same as that of 1).

Answer (score 0):

First draw the function.
We know that Volume is given by $\int_a^b \pi f(x)^2 dx$.
Therefore $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\pi \cos^2(x) dx$ and that's an easy integral.

While integrating along y axis your function will change to $\cos^{-1}x $ and hence integral will become $\int_0^1 \pi (\cos^{-1}(y))^2 dy$.

Comment: The limits are 0 and 1 because that's the only way the function will be greater that 0, and the 2 is because there are 2 parts, left and right from the y-axis?

Comment: Sorry there shouldn't be 2 if you are rotating around y axis because of symmetry of rotation. In my mind I  was still rotating it about x axis. I apologise for that confusion. The reason for limit 0 to 1 is because cos(x) along y axis is between 0 and 1. Hope that helps.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to the limit? Isn't that how far it will reach?

Comment: Just look at the graph of function cos(x) and if you are integrating along y axis the function will become its inverse (that's why cos^-1(x)) and limit of integration will be between 0 and 1.